# GoogleVR on Unity has error can't load libaudioplugingvrunity

Tags: google-vr

I am on Unity 5.3.3p3, and I've added the GoogleVR package to my project. I want to run the app on Moto X with Android 4.4.4. However, it crashes on startup, with messages that it cannot find 2 libraries. At least, I think that is the crashing error -- a backtrace prints after it. It also says it can't find the OVRPlugin, but I don't think I want that because Moto X is not a supported device and won't give me a oculussig file.

Here is from the log:

---

```
09-21 20:04:06.815 D/Unity   ( 2506): PlayerConnection already initialized - listening to [192.168.56.101:55144]

09-21 20:04:06.887 D/dalvikvm( 2506): Trying to load lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libaudioplugingvrunity.so 0xa5051820

09-21 20:04:06.903 D/dalvikvm( 2506): Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libaudioplugingvrunity.so 0xa5051820

09-21 20:04:06.903 D/Unity   ( 2506): Unable to lookup library path for 'libaudioplugingvrunity', native render plugin support disabled.

09-21 20:04:06.903 E/Unity   ( 2506): Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity

09-21 20:04:06.903 D/Unity   ( 2506): PlayerInitEngineNoGraphics OK

09-21 20:04:06.907 D/Unity   ( 2506): Unable to lookup library path for 'OVRPlugin', native render plugin support disabled.

09-21 20:04:06.907 E/Unity   ( 2506): Unable to find OVRPlugin

09-21 20:04:06.907 F/libc    ( 2506): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x827781bd (code=1), thread 2521 (UnityMain)

09-21 20:04:07.011 I/DEBUG   (  135): *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***

09-21 20:04:07.011 I/DEBUG   (  135): Build fingerprint: 'generic/vbox86p/vbox86p:4.4.4/KTU84P/eng.buildbot.20151118.000452:userdebug/test-keys'

09-21 20:04:07.011 I/DEBUG   (  135): Revision: '0'

09-21 20:04:07.011 I/DEBUG   (  135): pid: 2506, tid: 2521, name: UnityMain  >>> com.sample.GVR <<<

09-21 20:04:07.011 I/DEBUG   (  135): signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 827781bd

09-21 20:04:07.231 D/dalvikvm(  518): GC_EXPLICIT freed 723K, 24% free 10905K/14252K, paused 6ms+1ms, total 27ms

09-21 20:04:08.835 I/DEBUG   (  135):     eax 74206e69  ebx b77dcfe4  ecx 000000d0  edx 0395c4d5

09-21 20:04:08.839 I/DEBUG   (  135):     esi 0395c4d5  edi 94be833b

09-21 20:04:08.839 I/DEBUG   (  135):     xcs 00000073  xds 0000007b  xes 0000007b  xfs 00000000  xss 0000007b

09-21 20:04:08.839 I/DEBUG   (  135):     eip b77c38bf  ebp 6874206d  esp 939ee530  flags 00210246

09-21 20:04:08.863 I/DEBUG   (  135): 

09-21 20:04:08.863 I/DEBUG   (  135): backtrace:

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #00  pc 000068bf  /system/bin/linker (__dl__Z19dlsym_handle_lookupP6soinfoPKc+207)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #01  pc 0000118e  /system/bin/linker (__dl_dlsym+110)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #02  pc 002161db  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (LookupSymbol(void*, std::string const&)+43)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #03  pc 00905b96  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (LoadOVRPlugin(OVRPlugin*, char const*)+822)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #04  pc 009057f6  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (VRDeviceOculus::Initialize()+70)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #05  pc 00904351  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (CreateVRModule(VRDeviceType)+97)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #06  pc 009007a1  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (InitializeVRModule()::beforeInitializeEngineGraphics::Forward()+33)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #07  pc 003a6df6  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (InitializeGfxDevice(unsigned int)+54)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #08  pc 005a3336  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (UnityInitApplication()+1350)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #09  pc 005a4f92  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (UnityPlayerLoop()+450)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #10  pc 005a9902  /data/app-lib/com.sample.GVR-2/libunity.so (nativeRender(_JNIEnv*, _jobject*)+274)

09-21 20:04:08.867 I/DEBUG   (  135):     #11  pc 0002a4ab  /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+79)
```

---

If anyone knows or can point me in the right direction, thank you very much in advance !!

Comment: Is it crashing on Unity editor or only on the device?

Comment: Only on the device. And -- on Samsung S7, it plays, not crash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you're still experiencing this issue, it actually doesn't seem to be related to Google VR SDK.

> 09-21 20:04:06.903 E/Unity   ( 2506): Unable to find libaudioplugingvrunity

This line above is treated only as a warning, and, weirdly enough, it does not imply whether that library was loaded successfully or not at the end. To give you more context, it is just the way how Unity handles the third-party plugins in your project. While searching for these libraries, it may log this warning if the plugin library was not found in one of the expected paths, even though, if this search eventually finds the right plugin.

FYI, as you probably have noticed already, the actual reason of the crash is caused by the OVR library. One potential reason for this could be to not disabling Oculus SDK related options in your project, e.g. virtual reality support in player settings and/or Oculus audio spatializer plugin selection in project audio settings.

Cheers